# How to expose header information in API response message?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

I'm using spring's responseEntity response.

The response I've been using so far is return ResponseEntity.status(200).body(...); method, in this case the return data is in the form [ { ...}, {...} ].

Then, I checked the example, and there was a response header in front of this [ { ...}, {...} ].

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json;
charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 07 Oct 2018 11:53:46 GMT

[{"id":1,"username":"Jane"},{"id":2,"username":"John"}]
```

like this

Instead of checking the header separately, I want to check it together in the response message like this.

Did I misunderstand that the header message was arbitrarily moved?

Or is it possible?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Do you mean you want a specific header include in the body? If so, how do you want that formatted? What's the purpose?

Comment: To clarify, above the text [{...}, {...}]
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json; Hopefully the same information will be included.

You can simply interpret it as receiving a response from the user as shown in the code example in the question.

In JSON response, the person who sees the response wants to see information such as http status code and content-type as well as simple response data.

You could of course write this "by hand", but I think it's a bit different from that.

Comment: In most examples, "HTTP/1.1 200 Content-Type: application/json;" is written very identically.

Looking at this, it seems that this is not written by an individual, but "adds" header information configured in a certain system.

I want that behavior to be possible.

Comment: No idea what you are asking. Include actual controller code and expected response (wire i guess)\

Comment: I guess I got the answer somewhere else.
It can be said that I wanted to search the "HTTP/1.1 200 Content-Type: application/json" data included in the header in the "body" area.

However, this is meaningless, and I have come to the conclusion that it is correct to check it separately.